# Python MySQL: error inserting data

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Here is my code

```
qry = " INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_id,listing_id) VALUES ('%s','%s')"
cursor.execute(qry, ('123', '456',))
db_con.commit()
```

I am getting error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123'',''456'')' at line 1")
```

Comment: I think that is supposed to be `VALUES (%s, %s)`

Comment: @khelwood That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are using SQL parameters (yay!), and those *already take care of proper quoting*. You essentially double-quoted your values. Remove the quotes from the query:

```
qry = " INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_id,listing_id) VALUES (%s,%s)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  `double-quoted` quotes from the query:

```
qry = " INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_id,listing_id) VALUES (%s,%s)"
```